# Need compatible strobe trigger for Elinchrom Ranger AS with Nikon D7200 - fast?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, wireless-triggers

I am hoping someone can help me pretty quickly as I just landed a job on Monday and my old Skyport system is dead. I have an Elinchrom Ranger AS with location battery (kit) and a Nikon D7200.  I just need a way to fire my location light within 40 feet or so.

Anyone know of a reasonable unit /radio transmitter and receiver?

Comment: The Ranger AS *is* the location battery. What head are you using with it? Does it have a sync port?